# MySQL: WP usermeta table: get types, then names, then sort

Tags: mysql, wordpress, crosstab

I think this is a cross tab job, but I'm not seeing it!  In the Wordpress usermeta table, the data is like this:

```
| userid | meta_key | meta_value
| 123    | grant    | Education
```

And

```
| userid | meta_key | meta_value
| 123    | orgname  | ABC School
```

I need to search the table for all grant types of, say, 'Education', and then sort the results so that the org names are alphabetical.

The net result should effectively be a data set along these lines:

```
| userid | grant     | orgname
| 123    | Eductaion | ABC School
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Please note: these pages are not within wp itself, but are using the wp db. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explane a little more? or an example about what exacly want be your final result?

Comment: H Zalonis - I've added the third code block to show what I'd like to come out at the end. Thanks!

Comment: They are 2 tables with a foreight key userId? or you have nothing yet?

Comment: Hi - no, the first two examples above are from the same table, usermeta. The meta_key field can have any value, as can the meta_value. The userid field relates to the user table, and all of the extended info about the user is held in usermeta table and referenced by the userid field.

Comment: Yes I think I understant what do you want to do. Check if my answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this if it's what you want.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT userid ,meta_key, meta_value
FROM table
GROUP BY userid ";
$row = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$data = $array();
$i=0;
while( $res = mysql_fetch_array($row) )
{
  $data[$i] = $res;
  $i++;
}
echo "<table>";
for($i=0;$i<=count($data);$i+=2)
{
   echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>userid </td>";
      echo "<td>".$data[$i]['meta_key']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$data[$i+1]['meta_key']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>"

   $sql= "SELECT userid ,meta_key, meta_value
            FROM table
           WHERE userid = '".$data[$i]['userid']."' ";
   $row_sub = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   $j=0;
  while( $resSub = mysql_fetch_array($row_sub ) )
  {
    $subData[$j] = $resSub ;
    $j++;
  }

  for( $j=0;$j<=count($subData[$j]);$j+=2 )
 {
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$subData[$j]['userid ']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$subData[$j]['meta_value']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$subData[$j+1]['meta_value']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>"
 }
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Zalonis.  The code is giving me some errors, but I can see where you're going with it.  It's given me a couple of ideas which I will try out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( 123 );
  echo "<pre>";

  print_r( $all_meta_for_user ); // get all meta data of a particular user
  exit;
?>
```

look here for more [Get User Meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

Comment: Hi wordpresser - should've mentioned that the pages I'm working on are not within wp, but use data from the wp db.  Sorry, my mistake, I'll edit.